# Pip is not installed after downloading Python 2.7.15 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pip

For some reason, pip just isn't installed after installing Python 2.7.15 on Windows. I know that I had the option to install pip checked. I'm using the default path, "C:\Python27". This is the error I keep receiving: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Could someone offer guidance?

EDIT: There is no Scripts subfolder in my Python27 folder for some reason

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Windows 10 64 bit OS and i had initially installed python-2.7.amd64.msi downloaded from official website.

I had installed python in "C:\Program Files\Python27" path and pip was not working for Windows was unable to detect pip path.

So i tried to download get-pip.py file as mentioned in this [post](https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation#targetText=Pip%20install&targetText=There%20are%20many%20methods%20for,python%20get%2Dpip.py%20.) from this [link](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) but it did not work as well as the pip was not detected.

So I removed python (Control Panel > Add or Remove Program > Uninstall a Program > Python 2.7 64 bit).

And downloaded python-2.7.16.amd64.msi bug fix release from [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.16/python-2.7.16.amd64.msi) and reinstalled '*for all users*',, in '*C:\Python27*' path and enabled option to '*add python to environment variable*' during installation.

Now pip was working.

Python 2.7 installs pip in site-packages folder (C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip) by default. However, after I used pip to install first package (pillow in my case), the normal Scripts folder (C:\Python27\Scripts) was populated with pip as in Python 3.x versions.

Comment: This comment saved my life!!! For my case, I am using the official Windows 10 VM image from MSFT, and the python 2.7.15 windows installer just didn't install pip, nor does the get-pip.py worked on my VM, due to an outdated openssl installation. Thank you so much Anand!!

Answer (score 0):

Please check:

1. **pip.exe** in *C:\Python27\Scripts*
2. "C:\Python27\Scripts" in your **Path** environment variables

Comment: There is no Scripts subfolder for some reason

Comment: I donot think it was a valid installation, try to reinstall or follow @Ramanpreet Singh's solution with get-pip.py

Answer (score 0):

pip in located inside your "C:\Python27\Scripts" and you need to set its **path** to environment variables in order to access it from command prompt.

**STEPS TO ADD ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE:**

1. Open System Properties
2. Click Advanced system settings in the sidebar.
3. Click Environment Variables...
4. Select PATH in the System variables section
5. Click Edit
6. Add Python's path to the end of the list (the paths are separated by semicolons) C:\Python27

**ELSE you can install it with "get-pip.py".**

7. securely download get-pip.py.
8. Then run the following: python get-pip.py

**<--Link-->** : https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: There is no Scripts subfolder for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I installed Python2.7.18, and Scripts directory wasn't there.

I just run:
MyPython2.7Dir\python.exe -m ensurepip

That was all. Now I have the Scripts directory and pip installed as usual.

Comment: C:\Python27\python.exe: No module named ensurepip This is what I get when using your solution!